# Inserting line breaks into text output in shiny using cat

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to insert some line breaks using `cat` and `\n` into some text output using `shiny`.

Here are the relevant parts of my `ui.R` and `server.R`.

let's say I wanted to get the results of a t-test, and have a separate line for 't', 'df' and 'p-value'

I'm using shinydashboard layout.

## sample data

```
Group_A <- 1:13
Group_B <- 8:19
```

## ui

```
box(title = "T-test results:", status = "primary",  textOutput("text3"), width=3)
```

## server

```
output$text3 <- renderPrint({

  obj <-  t.test(Group_A, Group_B)

  cat("t = ", round(obj[[3]],3), "\n, df = ", round(obj[[2]],3), "\n, p-value = ", round(obj[[3]],5)) 

})
```

This output is shown in the image below:

[image]

As you can see, the output is across the screen left to right separated by a comma.  Because I want to add a number of results, I would like them to go top to bottom on the screen with a line break after each value.

Does anyone know how to do this in `shiny` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using `renderUI` and `htmlOutput`

```
library(shiny)
Group_A <- 1:13
Group_B <- 8:19

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      htmlOutput("text3")
      ),
    server = function(input, output){
      output$text3 <- renderUI({

        obj <-  t.test(Group_A, Group_B)
        HTML(
          paste0("t = ", round(obj[[3]],3), '<br/>', 
              "df = ", round(obj[[2]],3), '<br/>',
              "p-value = ", round(obj[[3]],5))
        )
      })
    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a paragraph tag with nothing inside like `tags$p("a"),`
[see here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/tag-glossary.html)